# Problem with .htaccess url rewriting

Tags: .htaccess

For the last 2 hours I have been fighting with this problem and trying to figure it out by myself. Coudn't do it.

So... I would like to rewrite my URL (www.domain.com/article/hello) to www.domain.com/article/read/hello, but I cann't seem to figure it out.
My current .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#problem here
RewriteRule ^article\/(.*)$ index.php/article/read/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#this has to stay the same and it's actually working
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

If I try to redirect the Rule that isn't working as it was supposed to (added R in the rule) -> Everything works alright, but that's not the point, I don't want it to redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.htaccess` works for me, I think it also works for you since you say it works if you do it with a redirect.

I added that rule and go to `localhost/article/hello` and then added `echo $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];` to the top of my index.php just to test and I got `/article/read/hello`

Maybe you're using something like `REQUEST_URI` which contains the `/article/hello` instead of `PATH_INFO` inside your index.php and that's why it seems like it's not working?

Comment: I was looking 2 hours in the wrong place. Aww.. Thanks, changed my REQUEST_URI and it works nicely now!